# Limiting the maximum file size to open

Tags: java, javafx

I open the image.

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setTitle("Open Image File");
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif", "*.bmp", "*.jpeg"));
selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

How to make a restriction on the opening of images no more than 1 mb?

Comment: What type is selectedFile?

Comment: @A1ex NS is this JavaFx or Swing? Or can you use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick solution** based on your approach:
Create a file filter and then use it with your `FileChooser`:

```
FileFilter myFilter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter ef = 
            new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif", "*.bmp", "*.jpeg");
        return ef.accept(file) && (file.length() <= (1024L * 1024L));
    }
};
fileChooser.setFileFilter(myFilter);
```

**A more elaborate example** is to define the file filter in a separate class:

```
public class MaxSizeFileFilter implements FileFilter {
  private final static long MAX_SIZE = (1024L * 1024L);
  private final static String SUFFIX_REGEX = ".*\\.(png|jpg|gif|bmp|jpeg)";

  @Override
  public boolean accept(File file) {
    try {
        return file != null &&
            file.isFile() &&
            file.canRead() &&
            file.getName().matches(SUFFIX_REGEX) &&
            file.length() <= MAX_SIZE;
    }
    catch (SecurityException exc) {
        System.err.println(exc.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The label is `JavaFX`. One of your solutions appears to be `Swing`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the class File, however [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace) seems to suggest that the getTotalSpace method returns the file size, in bytes.

If this is correct, then you can compare the size in mb to 1024, rejecting it if it exceeds this.

Rough example.

```
boolean valid = false;
final long sizeLimit = 1024 * 8;
while(!valid){
    selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(sizeLimit > selecteFile.getTotalSpace()){
         valid = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite. Do read carefully: "Returns the _size of the partition_ named by this abstract pathname. **returns [...] 0L** if this abstract pathname **does not name a partition**."